# DMX (Slave) with ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1 (Searching for advise)

Tags: c, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32, dmx512

I am currently working on a project where I want to integrate an ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1 into a DMX bus. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with microcontrollers, ESP32 and DMX. At least it is my first project in this direction.
I have looked through the Modbus example of espressif but do not understand how I can adapt it to DMX.
Does anyone have a tutorial on how to get started? Or how I program the ESP32 best. ESP with Arduino IDE is in my opinion much better to understand and programmable than the espressif Programming guid (2200 pages).

Comment: well DMX isn't Modbus so it's not really clear why a Modbus example would be a good starting point. As written, this question is far too broad since you basically ask "how do I make this thing?"

Comment: To respond to your second question: Arduino might be easier to start with, but if you intend to produce product-grade code, it's worth investing in learning how to use the ESP IDF, for a lot of reasons. And, while the IDF doesn't directly support DMX, once you have an IDF-based project, you can use the Arduino library within it.

Comment: If you prefer of using Arduino framework, you probably looking at the wrong documentation. You should read the documentation located [here](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/getting_started.html). There is an Arduino [OpenDMX library](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoDMX) which utilise RS-485 interface available.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a complete library for your purpose which also includes examples.
[github-esp_dmx](https://github.com/someweisguy/esp_dmx)
It is also able to use the RDM funtionality of DMX to make a two-way communication between the controller and the devices.